# AWK - change the file name (special characters)

Tags: awk

I have two files:

```
~/Pulpit/kot$ find . -name "*jpg" -printf "%f\n"
1.jpg
`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg
```

I want to change their name to:

```
_home_pic_Pulpit_kot_1.jpg

_home_pic_Pulpit_kot_`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg
```

I use this command:

```
~/Pulpit/kot$ find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk '{c=$0; gsub("/", "_", c)}{system("echo mv -v " $0 " " c)}'
mv -v /home/pic/Pulpit/kot/1.jpg _home_pic_Pulpit_kot_1.jpg
/bin/sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

**EDIT:**

This command works.

```
find $PWD -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0//\//_}"' {} \;
```

How to do the same with mawk?

**EDIT- 1:**

This solution works:

```
find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v '"'"'" a "'"'"'  '"'"'" $0 "'"'"'")}'
```

---

```
find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v '\''" a "'\'' '\''" $0 "'\'' ")}'
```

---

```
find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v \047" a "\047 \047" $0 "\047 ")}'
```

Comment: Do you really have a file named ``./`[~!($%^_&*){.}\___"`]`1.jpg``?  I am utterly horrified.  I generally stick to the [POSIX Portable Filename Character Set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_276).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes. I have a test file: See my edit.

Comment: I want to change "/" to "_" (as in gawk).

Comment: Are you sure `/` is in file name? Like in your output seems `./` is just added by find. Try `find . -name "*jpg" -printf "%f\n"` instead to output it without `./` in the begin.

Comment: @nowy I'm a bit confused by what you are doing.  `/` is never a valid character in a file name because it is the path separator.  Replacing `/` in a *path* means moving the files to a completely directory, not just a simple file name transformation.  Whereas `./file` is rather ordinary, `._file` is a dotfile / hidden file, whereas `dir/file` becomes `dir_file`.  Is that really what you intend?

Comment: Also the `awk` seems dangerous (try getting the quoting 100% correct and then convincing someone that the quoting is correct).  Use shell parameter expansion - it's probably safer, e.g. `find path ... -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0//\//_}"' {} \;`.

Comment: I fixed my post. Please read my edit.

Comment: This command works.
`find $PWD -name "*.jpg" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0//\//_}"' {} \;`

How to do the same with mawk?

Comment: @nowy Don't use mawk.

Comment: This solution works. `find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v '"'"'" a "'"'"'  '"'"'" $0 "'"'"'")}'` Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Why you want to use awk to generate a shell command? It seems very roundabout. There's probably a better way of doing whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @Gilles I asked just out of curiosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to put single quotes around the filename arguments to `mv`. It's ugly but...

change

```
system("echo mv -v " $0 " " c)
```

to

```
system("echo mv -v '"'"'" $0 "'"'"' '"'"'" c "'"'"'")
```

Comment: Your solution works.
Thank you very much.`find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v '"'"'" a "'"'"'  '"'"'" $0 "'"'"'")}'`

Comment: @nowy If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this isn't correct. Try with a `'` in the file name. Also, that `'"'"'"` is horribly unreadable. I recommend `'\''"` or `\047"`.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for your help. This is a good way:
`find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v '\''" a "'\'' '\''" $0 "'\'' ")}'`
or:
`find $PWD -name "*.jpg" | mawk 'a=$0{gsub("/", "_")}{system("mv -v \047" a "\047 \047" $0 "\047 ")}'`